# How to mock boolean variable having several && conditions with nested methods? MOCKITO FOR UNIT TEST

Tags: java, mockito

So, my problem is like this?
I have private method in which I am passing the variable `a` and these are the conditions for the boolean variable to be true.
I am having a class `B` having `getB()`, class `C` having `getC()` methods, interface `D` having `getD()` method with return type as `long`.
I am having another method (static boolean `isE()`) in which I am passing a local variable `f`
and calling method `getG()` from a different class `H`.

How do I mock these values for unit testing using Mockito so that my boolean variable `check` becomes `true`.

```
boolean check = a != null
                && a.getB().getC().getD() >= 0
                && !isE(f.getG()))
```

Comment: Are you sure that mocking is the right thing™ to do here? Usually mocking should be reserved for calls to external dependencies (database, webservice, network, etc.), not for overriding behavior of private methods. Have a look at the _strtategy pattern_, maybe this already helps in your case?

Answer (score 0):

you have to mock on an external call. if you are writing tests for class A..mock all the instances of Class B or Class C..like:

when(instance_of_class_b.someMethodOnClassB()).then(return true or false).

Mocking means mocking external calls from class.You cannot mock private calls within the same class,no meanning to that.

Check on Mockito library for more info

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot [test private methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34571/1744774) with JUnit/Mockito out of the box.

Secondly, your naming is confusing: You say „`B` having `getB()`“ and then you call the parameter `a` (for `a.getB()`). `B.getB()` is supposed to return a `C`, not a `B`, since `getC()` is invoked on it then. And you say „`C` having `getC()`“ and also „nested methods“. Furthermore, `D.getD()` doesn't return an object of type `D` but a `long`. I adapted all this according to what I thought you intended.

If you make your method in your class under test non-private it works as follows:

#### Surrounding classes for demonstration

```
class B {
    C getC() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
class C {
    D getD() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
interface D {
    default long getLong() {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

```
class E extends G {
}
```

```
class F {
    G getG() {
        return new E();
    }
}
```

```
class G {
}
```

#### Class under test

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

class Clazz {

    static boolean isE( final Object o ) {
        return o instanceof E;
    }

    F f;

    boolean method( final B b, final String origin ) {
        out.printf( "---- %s%nb=%s%n", origin, b );
        out.printf( "long=%s, original: %s%nisE=%s, original: %s%n",
                b != null ? String.valueOf( b.getC().getD().getLong() ) : "<not invoked>",
                ( new D() {} ).getLong(),
                isE( f.getG() ), Clazz.isE( new F().getG() ) );

        final boolean check = b != null
                && b.getC().getD().getLong() >= 0
                && ! isE( f.getG() );

        out.printf( "check=%s%n", check );
        return check;
    }
}
```

#### Test class

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.openMocks;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;

class ClazzTest {

    @InjectMocks
    Clazz clazz = new Clazz();

    @Mock private B b;
    @Mock private C c;
    @Mock private D d;
    @Spy private F f;

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach() {
        openMocks( this );
    }

    @Test
    void testMocked() {
        when( b.getC() ).thenReturn( c );
        when( c.getD() ).thenReturn( d );
        when( d.getLong() ).thenReturn( 0 );
        when( f.getG() ).thenReturn( new G() );

        assertTrue( clazz.method( b, "mocked" ) );
        assertFalse( clazz.method( null, "mocked" ) );
    }

    @Test
    void testOriginal() {
        assertFalse( clazz.method( null, "original" ) );
        assertThrows( NullPointerException.class, () -> clazz.method( new B(), "original" ) );
        System.out.println( "expected <NPE thrown>" );
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
---- mocked
b=b
long=0, original: -1
isE=false, original: true
check=true
---- mocked
b=null
long=<not invoked>, original: -1
isE=false, original: true
check=false
---- original
b=null
long=<not invoked>, original: -1
isE=true, original: true
check=false
---- original
b=igb.so.B@8dfe921
<expected NPE thrown>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detail reply,. This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the whole condition -> Extract to new method

This will create a new method. You can mock as you see fit and use it in your tests.